# Unable to view files in a browser with python http server

Tags: python, browser, httpserver

I am creating a python httpserver for a folder on remote machine using command :

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9999
```

But I am unable to view a file in the browser using this. As soon as click on the link the file gets downloaded. Is there a way to create a server so that i can view the files in my browser only.

Comment: What kind of file is it? PDF, image, MS Office, ...?

Comment: .sh .config etc extensions but the content inside is ascii. I am able to see .txt files although but i want to see other files as well

Comment: Check two things: 1) Can your browser display these files inline? 2) What is the `Content-Type` header of the HTTP response?

Comment: For .sh file , Content-type: application/x-sh

Comment: What OS are you running this server on?

Comment: chrome browser on mac os x. the httpserver is on linux machine

Comment: To force the browser to open non-html documents inline you can set the `Content-Disposition` response header to `inline`. You have to write your own HttpRequestHandler to do that.

Answer (score 8):

To make the browser open files inline instead of downloading them, you have to serve the files with the appropriate http `Content` headers.

What makes the content load inline in the browser tab, instead of as a download, is the header `Content-Disposition: inline`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

To add these headers, you you can subclass the default `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` with a custom one.

This is how it can be done using python 3. You have to modify the imports and maybe some other parts if you have to use python 2.

Put it in a executable script file which you can call `myserver.py` and run it like so: `./myserver.py 9999`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, test
import argparse


class InlineHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

    def end_headers(self):
        mimetype = self.guess_type(self.path)
        is_file = not self.path.endswith('/')
        # This part adds extra headers for some file types.
        if is_file and mimetype in ['text/plain', 'application/octet-stream']:
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
            self.send_header('Content-Disposition', 'inline')
        super().end_headers()

# The following is based on the standard library implementation 
# https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/http/server.py#L1195
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--bind', '-b', default='', metavar='ADDRESS',
                        help='Specify alternate bind address '
                             '[default: all interfaces]')
    parser.add_argument('port', action='store',
                        default=8000, type=int,
                        nargs='?',
                        help='Specify alternate port [default: 8000]')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    test(InlineHandler, port=args.port, bind=args.bind)
```

Comment: I was having trouble serving html content without .htm/.html extension using python3's http.server. Using method above I replaced `self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')` with `self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')` and now it works. Really useful snippet.

Comment: Couldn't view mhtml files after changing it to its content type `multipart/related` .

Answer (score 0):

Serving files like `foo.sh` should work fine using the  `SimpleHTTPServer`. Using `curl` as the client, I get a HTTP response like this:

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:9999/so.sh
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9999 (#0)
> GET /so.sh HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:9999
> Accept: */*
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/2.7.6
< Date: Thu, 02 Jun 2016 07:28:57 GMT
< Content-type: text/x-sh
< Content-Length: 11
< Last-Modified: Thu, 02 Jun 2016 07:27:41 GMT
< 
echo "foo"
* Closing connection 0
```

You see the header line

```
Content-type: text/x-sh
```

which is correct for the file `foo.sh`. The mapping from the file extensions `sh` to `text/x-sh` happens in `/etc/mime.types` on GNU/Linux systems. My browser

```
Chromium 50.0.2661.102
```

is able to display the file inline.

**Summary:** As long as you serve known files and your browser can display them inline, everything should work.

Comment: Content-type: application/x-sh is returned in my case

Comment: This probably depends on the configuration of your OS. Does your OS have a file `/etc/mime.types`? On my Ubuntu this includes a mapping from `sh` to  `text/x-sh`. Python probaly reads this configuration to set the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: yes i found this file and corresponding entry is application/x-sh  sh for me. thanks